# Scroll to form element

Tags: android, forms, scroll

I have a form with lots of fields and when I press the "submit" button, I'd like the scrollview to jump to the position where the unanswered field is located. Is there a method other than scrollto(x,y) to do this or such coordinates must always be mapped to the form's elements somehow ( something like (form element).getCoordinates() )?

Thanks

Comment: xain why are you not going for scrollto(x,y) I believ that would be easiest

Comment: That's the point, how can I get the (x,y) of - let's say - a radio button?

Comment: xain then in that case you can store the width &height of each view in a container(preferably arraylist to get the position to scroll to) using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight()

Comment: did any of the methods mentioned here worked for you??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScrollViews do have predefined methods [scrollTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,int%29) & [scrollBy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollBy%28int,int%29) for such functionality.

I believe you are having issues in getting co-ordinates. So I suggest store height of each view (that consumes vertical space)by using [View.getHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight%28%29) method & store heights in a [Map collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) .
Below is the code snippet I tried

```
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
               Integer emailTextViewHeight = (Integer)hashMap.get("EmailTextViewHeight");
            scrollView.scrollBy(0, emailTextViewHeight);//scrolls to emailTextView
                 }
             });
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work -

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus();
view.requestRectangleOnScreen(viewRectangle);
```

You can always take a look at the View class.

P.S. The unanswered field will be selected but I'm not sure that if it is out of the screen the Activity will scroll to the requested position.

Comment: calling view.requestFocusFromTouch() actually focus & make screen scroll to the view.